# in 'human being,' is 'being' a gerund?

Tags: be, being

In phrase "human being," is being a gerund?  I'm looking for a form of "be" that is present time, shows action/change/movement and does not require me using "human becoming."

Comment: No. In _human being, being_ is a noun. It can take articles, for instance: _a human being_. I have no idea what you are looking for -- _be_ has no meaning and can be inflected for tense, but it doesn't show action, change, movement, or anything else. It's part of the grammatical machinery, is all.

Comment: *Being* has the form of a gerund-participle, but in *human being* it long since passed into full nouniness. *Be* is ordinarily stative, and *being* exhibits activity (but not change) only when employed in a predicate designating behavior or role: *being good*, *being naughty*, *being a jerk*. In those cases it is less nouny than verbish.

Comment: _Human being_ is probably best treated as a compound noun. [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/being) shows these senses of _being_. Only in senses 3 is _being_ count (though rarely used without 'human' say after numerals):
a. A person: "The artist after all is a solitary being" (Virginia Woolf).
b. An individual form of life; an organism: "We [humans] are the only beings who are aware that we shall die" (Seyyed Hossein Nasr).
c. An imaginary, conjectural, or supernatural creature: extraterrestrial beings. // As FF says, it is deverbal in this usage. // Do you want _human development_?

Answer (score 3):

"Being" is a noun in "human being" and means "a living creature". In "human being", it is not a gerund (a form that is derived from a verb but that functions as a noun). In some cases, such as my first example below, it can be considered a gerund. It can function as a participle, but normally not in the phrase "human being".

---

Some examples of "being" include:

> Because of his being here, we should wait to discuss the deal.

> He is a human being.

> He is being annoying.